# How do i run .php on localhost using zend server?

Tags: php, zend-server, htdocs

I have installed Zend server. When i log on to Zend server, monitor and Server info, it says:

> Installation path: /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework

I can't access any of these folders, or even see that they exists on my mac.
How do i run the .php files using zend server?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr` is generally a hidden folder in Finder. You can access it though the Terminal.

Comment: Ok. But what should i do, and where should i save all my php files so that they will run?

Comment: Navigate to the path you want by typing it.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to find the Zend\Apache\htdocs folder where ever you have ZendServer stored.  Add your website files to the htdocs folder so you can run them in local host:

Example:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\index.php